# I tried to dynamically add a [Symbol.iterator] to the object to implement a custom iterator, but the TS total reports an error

Tags: typescript

I need to create custom iterators dynamically in TS, but the IDE ignores the dynamically added [Symbol.iterator] property, what should I do so that TS does not report an error?

#### normal example

This doesn't report an error, but it's not what I want

```
interface Type {
  [Symbol.iterator]: () => {
    end: boolean, next: () => { done?: boolean, value?: any }
  }
}

const string: Type = {
  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    return {
      end: false,
      next() {
        if (this.end === true) {
          this.end = false;
          return { done: true };
        } else {
          this.end = true;
          return { value: 123 };
        }
      }
    };
  }
}

console.log([...string]);
```

#### exception example

```
interface Type {
  [Symbol.iterator]?: () => {
    end: boolean, next: () => { done?: boolean, value?: any }
  }
}

const string: Type = {}

string[Symbol.iterator] = function () {
  return {
    end: false,
    next() {
      if (this.end) {
        this.end = false;
        return { done: true };
      } else {
        this.end = true;
        return { value: 123 };
      }
    }
  };
};

// Error: Type 'Type' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.ts(2488)
console.log([...string]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
// @ts-ignore
```

To ignore TypeScript errors, no other solution found so far.